# How can I evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^i} \binom{2i}{i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Evaluate $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\binom{2i}{i}}{k^i}\right),$$

where $k$ is a whole number.

I can't figure out how to approach this question, as no binomial series has such coefficients.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} z^n$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives: $$\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-4}}$$ for $k>4$. Not sure how it got it but maybe this could help you work backwards.    http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B2+i%2C+i%5D%2Fk%5Ei%2C+%7Bi%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D&dataset=

Comment: @gebruiker When editing titles, please keep in mind that [the height of any mathematical expressions should keep within the height of the surrounding text as much as possible](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles). Here it was already pretty bad with a binomial coefficient in the numerator, and it became even more ridiculous when you added the `\left` `\right` pair which padded the bottom as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, that

$$\binom{2i}{i}=(-4)^i\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{i}$$

> So, we can write OPs series as *binomial* series
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{k^i}
>   &=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{i}\left(-\frac{4}{k}\right)^i\\
>   &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{k}}}\\
>   &=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-4}}
>   \end{align*}
>
> convergent for $\left|-\frac{4}{k}\right|<1$, i.e. $k>4$.

---

**[2016-01-14]** Addendum

> We can extend the *[binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)* for *arbitrary* $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{\alpha}{n}:=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n(n-1)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1}
> \end{align*}
>   Putting $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}&=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{1}{2}-n+1\right)}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{2n-1}{2}\right)}{n!}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}(2n-1)!!\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n\binom{2n}{n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* and the relation $(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!$
- In (2) we use $(2n)!!=(2n)(2n-2)\cdots4\cdot2=n!2^n$

Comment: can the binomial-coefficients have negative indices? And, how did you arrive at that expression ?

Comment: @user3527361: I've added some details. Regards,